# Port Admob to mobile web

Tags: node.js, web-applications, admob, adsense, currency

I am in the depths of creating a mobile web game that I will soon release. I am interested in  monetizing this app. I want the game to feel like its a regular app and therefore wish to have admob ads (with deep links to the app store). I have heard that these also have substantially higher cpm that adsense mobile. My question is this: if I "port" admob using node.js will the clicks and views be recorded as server side, i.e. coming from one place, or mobile, i.e. from the user?

Here are some resources I am thinking of using:

https://media.admob.com/api/v1/docs/

https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-admob

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I am the author of the plugin you mentioned: https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-admob

The basic version has been deprecated, and the pro version is recommended: https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-admob-pro

Instead of porting AdMob to mobile web, you can consider use Cordova to pack your html5 game as a hybrid APP, then publish to Apple AppStore or Google Play Store.

Use the AdMob plugin to present Ad in your app, then Google will pay you.

Only a few javascript lines to present the Ad, and the AdMob SDK will take care of Ad presenting and user click.

See the example code:

```
    function onLoad() {
    if(( /(ipad|iphone|ipod|android|windows phone)/i.test(navigator.userAgent)   )) {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', initApp, false);
    } else {
        initApp();
    }
}
var admobid = {};
if( /(android)/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) { 
    admobid = { // for Android
        banner: 'ca-app-pub-6869992474017983/9375997553',
        interstitial: 'ca-app-pub-6869992474017983/1657046752'
    };
} else if(/(ipod|iphone|ipad)/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    admobid = { // for iOS
        banner: 'ca-app-pub-6869992474017983/4806197152',
        interstitial: 'ca-app-pub-6869992474017983/7563979554'
    };
} else {
    admobid = { // for Windows Phone
        banner: 'ca-app-pub-6869992474017983/8878394753',
        interstitial: 'ca-app-pub-6869992474017983/1355127956'
    };
}

// it will display smart banner at top center, using the default options
if(AdMob) AdMob.createBanner( {
    adId: admobid.banner, 
    position: AdMob.AD_POSITION.TOP_CENTER, 
    autoShow: true } );
```